# Avoid flickering when replacing element content using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have something like this on my site, to make things a bit more difficult for spam harvesters. By default the site shows "noob (at) me (dot) com", but then JavaScript replaces this text with the actual email address.

```
<span id="email">noob (at) me (dot) com</span>

<script type="text/javascript" src="email.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('email').innerHTML = emailProducingFunction();
</script>
```

This works. However, the problem is that sometimes, the original text is shown for a split second before JS turns to the real email, causing a brief "blinking" effect when the site loads.

Is it possible to avoid this somehow?

One "solution" is to have the email element hidden using CSS, and then use JS to make it unhidden. However, this is not a good solution because the site should also be compatible with browsers that have CSS enabled but JS disabled.

Comment: How about showing no email address at first and then just insert the correct one? As I understand the question, it's just a dummy mail address anyway...

Comment: Most email scrapers know about that kind of obfuscation, it's no problem to work around.

Comment: Have your tried loading the scripts in the `HEAD` of the document, using the DOMReady hook from your favourite JavaScript library? That may work.

Comment: If this solution needs to work with JS disabled websites how will you replace the email? Set `display: none` and if JS disabled then `noob (at) me (dot) com` should be hidden anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of resolving your flickering issue may I propose something else that doesn't suffer from the same phenomenon.

### Alternatives to email obfuscation

Instead of mitigating flickering have you ever considered worthy alternatives like reversing email addresses and then using CSS to show them correctly? This technique may not be best in terms of screens readers and copy-pasting, but there are others worth using that work differently to yours.

[Check this answer on Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/235965/5375)

This answer summs up [this study](http://techblog.tilllate.com/2008/07/20/ten-methods-to-obfuscate-e-mail-addresses-compared/) about different email obfuscation techniques. CSS reversing seems to be one of the most effective ones.

[image]

### Using CSS reversing and clickability/selection

So your technique replaces all emails on your page on load using Javascript. CSS solution correctly displays reversed emails but if one would then click such an email or selec it (for copy) they'd get a reversed email back.

So using CSS and improving these everyday scenarios can be done by using javascript which is a similar solution to yours except that it only executes on demand (and not always as in your case). It's easy to attach a click/select event to an element and reverse its content when required.

What I'm trying to say is that even when using CSS obfuscation one may not lower usability of their website. It can still be done.

Comment: This study does not take into account user experience, which is far better with the solution exposed in this question; furthermore, the volume of spam received when the JS solution is used is very small.

Comment: @JulienRoyer: I updated my answer to state this fact. What you're saying is of course true but I'm not pinpointing one technique only. There are others that I point to outlined in the *other* Superuser question that one can use to satisfy their needs.

Comment: @JulienRoyer: And interestingly enough... One of the largest sites on the world (Facebook) uses a different completely usability bad technique by changing emails to images. If it works for them I don't know why email reversing shouldn't work for us. You also have to ask yourself this question: **How many screen-reader users does your website have?** If you have a news site, then this should be considered, but if you're publishing i.e. development related content then you can likely just forget about this...

Comment: I agree, every solution available out there should be studied before making a choice. I like the obfuscated/JS solution because it seems like a good trade-off. As for the image solution used by Facebook, it requires a complex library capable of generating non OCR-able images; furthermore, its problems are not limited to screen-readers: copy-paste is also an issue here.

Comment: @JulienRoyer: Email harvester bots are too dumb to OCR images. If they can't read CSS reversed emails I bet they won't read images either.

Comment: @JulienRoyer: But as you say (and are right) there's more to usability than simply screen readers... Clickability and copy pasting can easily be supported by javascript handlers that manipulate these emails on demand which makes is a similar solution (javascript) but better because they only execute on demand (if used at all).

Answer (score 3):

This flickering happens because the original address is shown, the email.js script is loaded, then the function is applied. The file loading + function execution leaves enough time for the flickering to happen.

The solution is to put the script tags before the original address is shown. However, if you just try to use the #email element, you'll get an error because it doesn't exist. So you can use the `DOMContentLoaded` event to wait for the element to exist. (`$(document).ready()` if you're used to jQuery.)

Using this way, there won't be any flickering.

Example:

```
<script src="email.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('email').innerHTML = emailProducingFunction();
}, false);
</script>

<span id="email">noob (at) me (dot) com</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `js` class to your `body` element when the page begins to load:

```
<body>
  <script>document.body.className += " js";</script>
  <style>body.js #email {display: none;}</style>
```

thus making sure that the "obfuscated" address is shown to "non-JS" users only.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<script>` element to be **before** the email element:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="email.js"></script>

<span id="email">noob (at) me (dot) com</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('email').innerHTML = emailProducingFunction();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources regarding [Flash of unstyled content (FOUC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content);

http://paulirish.com/2009/avoiding-the-fouc-v3/

http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/

http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/10/1-way-to-avoid-the-flash-of-unstyled-content

Comment: I don't think that FOUC is relevant here; this is a JS problem.

Comment: Well, it shows the default output until it´s modified by the javascript.